# Cartthrob clear_cart input not working on update_cart_form

Tags: cartthrob

As the title says - cart just reloads:

```
{exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form 
    class="validate"
    id="form-basket"
    return="shop/basket"
    secure_action="yes"
    }

    basket code here

    <button type="submit" name="clear_cart">Empty Basket</button>

{/exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form}
```

Any idea why this might be the case?

EE is 2.7.2, CT is Pro 2.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using an input instead of a button

```
<input type="submit" name="clear_cart" value="Empty Basket">
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why I didn't think of that in the first place! Thanks @mjr.

Comment: awesome, glad you got it sorted!